# Using a fast implementation of Fernet in Python

Tags: python, encryption, python-cryptography

I'm using the excellent `cryptography` package to decrypt data that was encrypted with the Fernet encryption. This package's implementation of Fernet is in pure-Python, which can be slow.

Are you familiar with a Python package that provides Fernet encryption that's implemented in C, so it's faster?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [pycryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome)
It implements a lot of cryptographic algorithms in c
Note, it is imported in python as `Crypto` rather than `pycryptodome`

The [documentation](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/examples.html#encrypt-data-with-aes) shows how to use AES for symmetric encryption which is what `cryptography.Fernet` uses.